# Problems with including external JS file to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I've read many tutorials and tried them, but they don't work.
Just for example I wrote this simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
<body>
    <p id="testElement"> Html text</p>

<script>
     var paragraph = document.getElementById("testElement");
     paragraph.innerHTML = "Test Message";
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I get `Test Message` text in my page.

Then I put my JS code to an external file: '`/js/js.js`'

```
var paragraph = document.getElementById("testElement");

paragraph.innerHTML = "Test Message";
```

And modify the HTML file to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/js.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>

    <p id="testElement"> Html text</p>

</body>
</html>
```

When I open the HTML file in a browser, I only get `Html text`. My JS does not work. Please explain what I am doing wrong.

Comment: try to put your `<script>` tag just before `</body>` The problem here is that `<p id="testElemet">` is not in the DOM when your JS file is executed.

Comment: I put my <script> after <p> and before </body>  - doesn’t work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that javascript linked in head is executed before the body is loaded, so you can just put the script at the end of the body like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p id="testElement"> Html text</p>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try that - get the same result.

Comment: @pj-infest I tried it, it works. Maybe your js.js file has wrong location.

Comment: now i put js file to the same folder, and cange filepath to src="/js.js" , but it desn’t work.
It is not a problem with code now.  I try install another brouther

Comment: @pj-infest just remove the slash like this: `src="js.js"` .Then it works.

Comment: I tryed to do that before wite post here. It doesn’t work too.

Comment: Install another brouther - get the same wrong result

Comment: @pj-infest look into the console in Chrome or Firefox, you should find errors there.

Comment: Good idea. Firefox console say that: TypeError: paragraph is null.

but I initialize variable  
var paragraph = document.getElementById("testElemet");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95590/discussion-between-makadlcik-and-pj-infest).

Answer (score 2):

Check the JavaScript error console.

Your code runs before the document is rendered so the node `testElemet` doesn't exist.
Either move your script-include down as the last element in the body or wrap your code in a load/ready event.

```
function on_document_ready(callback) {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        callback();
    } else {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback);
    }
}

on_document_ready(function () {
    var paragraph = document.getElementById("testElemet");

    paragraph.innerHTML = "Test Message";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work fine:

```js
var paragraph = document.getElementById("testElement");
paragraph.innerHTML = "Test Message";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="testElement">Html text</p>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/js.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Please make sure that `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/js.js"></script>` is placed just before `</body>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var doSomething = function()
{
 var paragraph = document.getElementById("testElement");

 paragraph.innerHTML = "Test Message";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload = "doSomething();">

       <p id="testElement"> Html text</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Try saving both the files in the same folder.

Make use of your browsers developer console, to determine whether any errors have occurred.

Regarding 'onload', you can have a look at this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp).